# Recommend a Server Side Media Encoder or SDK

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, encoder, smooth-streaming

I'm writing a video on demand solution. I want to take care of the end to end process, from ingestion of content to playback.

I have decided to utilise IIS Smooth Streaming for the method of delivery, which means all the video content must be encoded as H246 Adaptive Streaming Video.

I originally started using Azure for this project, but I as dove deeper I realised this really was too big a platform for what I need. It loaded unnecessary work and complexity for what I'm trying to achieve.

The 'issue' I'm having is with choosing an appropriate method to encode uploaded content. There are many encoding packages available but I can't find one which meets my criteria. 
I'm happy to use an off the shelf package or write something with an appropriate SDK.

1. Must operate on Windows Server 2012
2. Must operate while the interactive user is logged off (i.e. as a windows service)
3. Ideally notify when the job is complete (can be an indirect method)
4. Ideally create a thumbnail
5. Invoking the encode process can be simple command line, watch folder or API / SDK
6. Must on on my server, not a cloud service
7. Must encode H264 Adaptive Streaming for IIS

I've tried:

- Expression Encoder - Doesn't work in 2012, and no longer developed by MS
- Sorenson Squeeze - Almost works, but leaves itself open when launched from command prompt so each time it encodes so I'd end up with 100's of instances
- Azure .. too big & expensive

I know Sorenson has an server product which can be self-hosted, but this is cost prohibitive. 
MainConcept have several SDK's and I've emailed them, however they don't list prices so this to me means expensive. (You may have noticed cost is a big factor. I'm one guy and a company)

Can anyone recommend a .NET SDK (c#) SDK or encoder package which will hit my criteria?

Many thanks

Comment: Turns out expression encoder does work on 2012, providing you use the sdk and not the GUI. This would be ideal, if it was still a supported product.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.ffmpeg.org/

While not a .net solution, it's free, and meets most of your criteria

I've not used it for adaptive streaming video, but apparently it supports it

It's all done from the command line - depending on what you want to do, you may need to write a wrapper for it (we had to do this for monitoring folders/databases and for notifications when complete), but i've successfully used it in the past to encode tens of gigs of video on a daily basis

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own service in c# or directly run it in IIS application with the needed permission.

Using ffmpeg :

http://vbffmpegwrapper.codeplex.com/

https://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/

Using vlc:

https://code.google.com/p/libvlc-sharp/

http://libvlcnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Rhozet Promedia Carbon is the tool you're looking for. Supports all your needs. You can request a free demo. They handle all the licensing for the formats.

http://www.harmonicinc.com/product/promedia-carbon

Any tool you might want for this is going to be cost-prohibitive due to licensing.

As others have mentioned, your other option is FFMpeg